# How do I build up an array using let in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

(test [1 2 3]) is returning [], not [1 2 3], why?

```
(defn test [some-array]
      (let [x []]
        (doseq [i some-array]
          (conj x i))
        x))

(test [1 2 3])
```

EDIT: a comment below suggested I am trying an imperative approach with a functional language, and that's probably correct. What I am trying to do is build up a vector of vectors using an initial sequence of values (inside a vector in this case) as starting data. I guess I could try to transform each value in the vector and return it, but that seems harder conceptually (from an imperative mindset) than taking a starting vector and using it to build out a new one and return that.

As an example, suppose I had a function that takes `1` and returns `"one"`, and I wanted to have a function take `[1 2 3]` and return `[[1 "one"][2 "two"][3 "three"]]`.

Comment: I just realized I am confusing the ideas of arrays and vectors... not sure that is part of the problem here.

Comment: Also, tried `for` instead of `doseq` with the same result... curious about the difference between those two, though.

Comment: It's very hard to guess (at least for me), what you are actually after.
Could you please be specific, what transformation is in your mind?  Do
you want to `map` each item of `some-var` or do you want to
shrink/increase the items etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure's focus is on immutable data and functional programming.  Your
code there feels like you want to do some imperative style ideas here.

Your `test` there could as well be `identity` - a copy of some immutable
data structure, is just the immutable data structure itself.

If your example there is oversimplified and you want to "append" to some
`x` with data inside it, you could use `into`.

#### edit

To transform a sequence one-by-one (e.g. each input results in
a different output), use `map` (or `mapv` to get a vector and make it
eager).  E.g.

```
(def numbers
  {1 "one"
   2 "two"
   3 "three"})

(defn test [some-array]
  (mapv #(vector % (numbers %)) some-array))

(println (test [1 2 3]))
; → [[1 one] [2 two] [3 three]]
```

(Bonus points for using `juxt` as mapping function)

Comment: This is what I was sensing... I seem to be recreating a JS scenario. Not that it couldn't be done 'right' in JS... I just mean the typical JS approach.

Comment: I _think_ you want to copy `some-array`, but there is no apparent need
for that. You still could use `into` to create a new container, that
holds all items of `some-array`.

Comment: I added an edit to my original post to clarify things (or maybe confuse things!).

Comment: Your suggestion (via your edit) is so succinct! Wow.

Comment: Also, intermediate variables are really the thing that has gotten so tired for me... so very happy to move away from `let` when I can.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, some ways of building the result are easier than others. In this case, we see that each element of the result vector is computed from a corresponding  element in the input vector. This is a good indication to use `map` (or `mapv`):

```clj
(def nums ["zero" "one" "two" "three" "four" "five"])

(defn arr-test [xs]
  (mapv (juxt identity nums) xs))
```

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to do it that way - but if you *did* :-) you'd want to use `loop` instead of `let`:

```
(defn arr-test [some-array]
  (let [digit-words {1 "one", 2 "two",   3 "three", 4 "four", 5 "five",
                     6 "six", 7 "seven", 8 "eight", 9 "nine", 0 "zero" }]
    (loop [x []
           a some-array]
      (if (empty? a)
        x
        (recur (conj x [(first a) (digit-words (first a))]) (rest a))))))
```

A better way would be:

```
(defn arr-test [some-array]
  (let [digit-words {1 "one", 2 "two",   3 "three", 4 "four", 5 "five",
                     6 "six", 7 "seven", 8 "eight", 9 "nine", 0 "zero" }]
    (mapv #(vector % (digit-words %)) some-array)))
```

Comment: This is handy to know... however, it looks like I should take the functional approach. I also just read that I should avoid arrays as opposed to vectors unless I need something specific from the Java ecosystem. Thanks for this!

Comment: The "recur loop" solution is what I worked out first when I was starting to learn Clojure, so I think of it as "beginning Clojure". "It's Clojure, Jim - but not as we know it!". :-) The second is the "better way" - using functions to do the work, which is also clearer (once you know what all those dang functions do :-)

Answer (score 1):

there is also a handy util `clojure.pprint/cl-format` in core library to get string representation of numbers (and much more!):

```
user> (def num-str (partial clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~R"))
#'user/num-str

user> (mapv (juxt identity num-str) [0 1 2 234 2455323 1541524152352356235625])
;;=> [[0 "zero"]
;;    [1 "one"]
;;    [2 "two"]
;;    [234 "two hundred thirty-four"]
;;    [2455323
;;     "two million, four hundred fifty-five thousand, three hundred twenty-three"]
;;    [1541524152352356235625N
;;     "one sextillion, five hundred forty-one quintillion, five hundred twenty-four quadrillion, one hundred fifty-two trillion, three hundred fifty-two billion, three hundred fifty-six million, two hundred thirty-five thousand, six hundred twenty-five"]]
```

Comment: Whoa. I've never seen that before.